# Sequence Converges to Infinity in a Topological Space

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence, compactness

I'm trying to work through the following as part of a larger problem that I'm working on:

> Invent a precise definition for the phrase "a sequence $\{x_{k}\}$ converges to infinity" in a topological space $X$. (The definition should apply, in particular, to $X=\mathbb{R}^{n}$, should not mention distance functions, and should include the phrase "for every compact subset $K\subset X$".)

I know that in a space $(X,\tau)$, a sequence $\{x_{k}\}$ is said to converge to a point $x_{0}\in X$ if, for each neighborhood $U$ of $x_{0}$, there exists an $N\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ such that $x_{n}\in U$ for each $n\geq N$. I also know that a "neighborhood of infinity" is a subset of $X$ which contains the complement of a closed and compact subset of $X$.

*My attempt*. I think the definition should read as follows.

> **Definition.** A sequence $\{x_{k}\}$ *converges to infinity* in a topological space if, for each complement of a closed and compact subset $K$ of $X$, there exists a subset $U$ of $X$ containing $K^{c}$ and an there exists an index $N\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ such that $x_{n}\in K$ for all $n\geq N$.

I think working the definitions together is what I needed to do, but I'm not sure if this works. Does my "definition" look okay, or is there something wrong with it? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $U$ is superfluous and could be replaces by $X\setminus K$ right away, provided $K$ is closed too:

For every compact (and closed, but this is superfluous in Hausdorff spaces) subset of $X$, there is some $N$ such that for all $n \ge N$, $x_n \notin K$.

This exactly means that $x_n \to \infty$ in the so-called Aleksandrov extension of $X$, a generalisation of the one-point compactification.

Answer (score 1):

You can rather try "$(x_k)$ converges to infinity if for all compact $K$ of $X$, there exists a $N \geqslant 0$ such that $\forall n > N, x_n \notin K$".

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Shouldn't it be "for all $n>N$, $x_{n}\notin K$"?

Answer (score 1):

Your definition seems quite complicated. Also, I don’t understand what’s the use of $U$.

I would say: **a sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $\infty$ if any compact $K$ contains only a finite number of terms of the sequence.**